# Weekly Users vs Installations

Tags: google-chrome-app, android-pay, chrome-web-store

I'm checking on the Chrome Web Store's Developer Dashboard and I'm trying to understand what the column "Weekly Users" mean. Is it the *obvious* meaning (as in actual usage)?

I'm asking because I noticed the number of users (5) doesn't match the number of purchasers (4) (From Google Wallet). Is this a non-unique user count?

Thanks,
-Daniel

Comment: FYI, from looking at the numbers it seems like this is actual usage. Don't forget (like I did) that you may have a local copy running or installed the copy from your own web store link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the weekly numbers stat is just that - the number of 7-day active users. It's not the number of people who have installed an application.